# Undefined method `_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a little problem with creating new object, called "round". I'm getting the following error:

> NoMethodError in Rounds#new
>
> undefined method `rounds_path'

rounds_controller.rb:

```
  def new
    @round = Round.new
  end

  def create
    @round = Round.new(round_params)
  end

  private

  def round_params
    params.require(round).permit(:tournament_id)
  end
```

View for action new:

```
      %h2 New round
      = simple_form_for @round do |r|
        = r.input :number, label: 'Round number'
        = r.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Routes.rb:

```
  resources :tournaments do
    resources :rounds
  end
```

I think that problem is in nesting, but I don't know where exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails guesses at routes, which is useful.  Because you're only passing round it routes to `rounds_path`, so as you suspect it's because you've nested it.  Change this

```
= simple_form_for @round do |r|
```

to

```
= simple_form_for [@tournament, @round] do |r|
```

As Max says, you will need to have got the tournament.  I assumed you'd have done this with a `before_action` in your controller.  I would then create rounds via the tournament personally

```
class RoundsController

  before_action :set_tournament

  def new
    @round = @tournament.rounds.new
  end

  def create
    @round = @tournament.rounds.new(round_params)
  end

  private

  def set_tournament
    @tournament = Tournament.find(params[:tournament_id])
  end

  def round_params
    params.require(:round).permit(:number)
  end
end
```

Comment: This solution expects you to have defined `@tournament` as well as `@round`.

Comment: @MaxWilliams he has nested routes, so I assumed he'd have had it, but updated my answer. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the url to which the simple form will post to.

```
%h2 New round
      = simple_form_for @round, url: tournament_rounds_path(tournament_id: params[:tournament_id]) do |r|
        = r.input :number, label: 'Round number'
        = r.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

For future reference, you can check the actual routes that your `routes.rb` creates by running `rake routes` on your terminal.

Comment: It works, but saved round does not have foreign key (tournament id).

Comment: Apologies. I updated my answer. You should be able to get the tournament id from the `params` and then pass it to the `tournament_rounds_path` like so: `tournament_rounds_path(tournament_id: params[:tournament_id])`

Comment: Still does not work. Probably problem lies elsewhere, because in server console I can see parameters such as tournament id or round number.

Comment: Ok I just realized that your code inside `def round_params` is wrong. Add this instead: `params.require(:round).permit(:number, :tournament_id)`